# Javascript RegEx safari issue

Tags: javascript, regex, browser, safari, word-boundaries

This is a word boundary Regular Expression which support non latin letters , it works in Chrome but not in Safari. any alternative solution?

```js
new RegExp("(?<=[\\s,.:;\"']|^)" + word + "(?=[\\s,.:;\"']|$)","g");
```

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't `new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b","g");` work?

Comment: \b support only latin letters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9).  i want to work this on indian languages

Answer (score 1):

Look behind assertions are not supported in Safari. Check compatibility table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Browser_compatibility)
Instead you can try without it.

```regex
const regx = new RegExp("([\\s,.:;\"']|^)("+word+")([\\s,.:;\"']|$)","g");
```

**Example**

```js
let word="word";
const regx = new RegExp("([\\s,.:;\"']|^)("+word+")([\\s,.:;\"']|$)","g");
console.log('hello word, beautiful word'.replace(regx,'$1World$3'));
```

Comment: its also selecting the white space , Want to avoid the first white space too.

Comment: @Sarath I have updated the answer with code. Please check.

Comment: 'hello word, beautifull word'.replace(regx,'World') => "helloWorld beautifullWorld" , i want "hello World beautifull World"

Comment: @Sarath I have updated my answer above. please check.